# Swapping columns and rows in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I have data in my table that looks like the below.

*Name*                  |*Course*             |*Results* 
John Smith          |Maths               |Passed
John Smith          |Statistics                |Failed
John Smith          |Accounting            |Passed
Edward Brown     |Maths               |Passed
Edward Brown     |Statistics          |Passed
Edward Brown     |Accounting       |Passed
Michael Jordan    |Maths               |Passed
Michael Jordan    |Statistics          |Passed
Michael Jordan    |Accounting       |Failed

and I want to display this data in my report like this:

*Name*                     |*Maths*           |*Statistics*          |*Accounting*
John Smith             |Passed         |Failed              |Passed
Edward Brown        |Passed         |Passed                    |Passed
Michael Jordan       |Passed         |Passed            |Failed
I am on SQL Server 2008.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Matrix.
2. Set the Rows value to Name.
3. Set the Columns value to Course.
4. Set the Data value to Statistics.

Let me know if you need any more detail.

Comment: I am fairly new to SSRS. On the report I named my columns (the header row) as: Name Maths Statistics Accounting. Please note Statistics is one of the courses.